# Keep the unique value of duplicate removal

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Having a dataframe with duplicates (only one column) like this:

```
df  <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"))
```

How is it possible to have a new df which will have the unique value of duplicates?

Example of expected output

```
df  <- data.frame(id = c("A","B","C"))
```

What I tried is this. It has a level but I think this is not the solution:

```
df$id[duplicated(df$id)]
[1] A A B B C
Levels: A B C
```

Comment: try `df[!duplicated(df$id), , drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `distinct` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% distinct()
df2
#   id
# 1  A
# 2  B
# 3  C
```

If there are columns other than `id`, we can do the following to compare duplicates only in `id` and keep all other columns.

```
df2 <- df %>% distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
df2
#   id
# 1  A
# 2  B
# 3  C
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't we simply use `unique` from base-r?

```
> unique(df)
  id
1  A
4  B
7  C
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
unique( df )
  id
1  A
4  B
7  C
```

does the job. You can assign this to a new data.frame

```
df2 <- unique( df )
```

If there are other columns that you want untouched, limit the call to the first column:

```
df2 <- unique( df[ 1 ] )
```